# Why is packet.pts != frame->pkt_pts in AVFrame?

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to understand some audio/video sync issues via ffmpeg, I noticed the following. Running this code

```
while (av_read_frame(formatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
{
   if (packet.stream_index == videoStream)
   {
      avcodec_decode_video2(videoCodecCtx, frame, &got_frame, &packet);
   }

   printf("packet.pts = %d\n", packet.pts);
   printf("frame->pkt_pts", frame->pkt_pts);
}
```

shows that frame->pkt_pts in general differs from packet.pts, despite the documentation claiming that frame->pkt_pts is the

> PTS copied from the AVPacket that was decoded to produce this frame

Moreover I noticed that the difference between the two is big exactly at the places where audio and video are out of sync.

So, why is `packet.pts != frame->pkt_pts` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Video may have delayed frames, which means the input frame and output frame may refer to differently ordered units. E.g. in case of MPEG, display order of IBP is coded as IPB, and the pts of input is different from output, and the reordering introduces delay between input pts and output pts. Additionally, when using multi-threaded decoding, an additional delay of n_threads - 1 packets is added between input and output. In all these cases, pkt.pts != frame->pkt_pts. For display, you should rely on frame->pkt_pts.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `avcodec_decode_video2(videoCodecCtx, frame, &got_frame, &packet)` may not actually decode `packet` but some packet that came earlier? Note that in my case, all frames are keyframes (encoded with lagarith). I have noted that frame->pkt_pts actually seems to lag behind packet.pts by 2 units consistently. According to your explanation, this would fit with the first two calls of avcodec_decode_video2 failing to decode any frame. P.S.: Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: For keyframes, this is because we use multi-threaded decoding. So, assume you have 2 threads, and each thread decodes an independent keyframe. In order for all of them to work, the first 2 calls to decode_video2() consume a packet and return immediately, without returning a decoded frame. The threads decode each frame in the background. The third call to decode_video2() blocks waiting for the first one to return, and as soon as it does, it gives it a new packet to decode, and you get the first returned. So the lag is then 2, even thought it's keyframe-only.

Comment: Any chance you can comment on this, @RonaldS.Bultje? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210518/ffmpeg-avformat-avcodec-unexpected-pts-dts-values-are-written-to-output-when