# ffmpeg avformat / avcodec unexpected pts / dts values are written to output when encoding video

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I try to follow the examples for encoding video using ffmpeg C API given in https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html and https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_video_8c-example.html

I put together the following code to do some very simple encoding

```
void encode(AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx, AVCodecContext* enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt) {
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            return;

        } else if (ret < 0) {
            std::printf("Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        std::printf("pts=%zd dts=%zd\n", pkt->pts, pkt->dts);
        av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
    }
}

int main() {
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_ERROR);

    AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx = nullptr;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&fmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, "f:/videoOut.mp4");
    AVStream* videoStream = avformat_new_stream(fmt_ctx, NULL);
    const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

    int w = 100;
    int h = 100;
    codec_ctx->width = w;
    codec_ctx->height = h;
    codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    codec_ctx->time_base = { 1, 10 };
    codec_ctx->framerate = { 10, 1 };
    codec_ctx->gop_size = 20;
    codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 4;

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(videoStream->codecpar, codec_ctx);
    avio_open(&fmt_ctx->pb, fmt_ctx->url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    avformat_write_header(fmt_ctx, NULL);

    AVPacket* videoPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, NULL);
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->format = codec_ctx->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = codec_ctx->width;
    frame->height = codec_ctx->height;

    av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    av_frame_make_writable(frame);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        av_frame_make_writable(frame);

        for (int y = 0; y < codec_ctx->height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < codec_ctx->width; x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = i * 4;
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < codec_ctx->height / 2; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < codec_ctx->width / 2; x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 20 + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 20 + i * 2;
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;
        encode(fmt_ctx, codec_ctx, frame, videoPacket);
    }

    encode(fmt_ctx, codec_ctx, nullptr, videoPacket);
    
    av_write_trailer(fmt_ctx);
    avio_close(fmt_ctx->pb);

    av_packet_free(&videoPacket);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx);
}
```

this will output the following pts and dts values directly before handing over to `av_interleaved_write`

```
pts=0 dts=-2
pts=5 dts=-1
pts=2 dts=0
pts=1 dts=1
pts=3 dts=2
pts=4 dts=3
pts=10 dts=4
pts=7 dts=5
pts=6 dts=6
pts=8 dts=7
pts=9 dts=8
pts=15 dts=9
pts=12 dts=10
pts=11 dts=11
pts=13 dts=12
pts=14 dts=13
pts=19 dts=14
pts=17 dts=15
pts=16 dts=16
pts=18 dts=17
pts=20 dts=18
pts=24 dts=19
pts=22 dts=20
pts=21 dts=21
pts=23 dts=22
```

But when I afterwards examine the written file using the command `ffprobe videoOut.mp4 -show_frames > frames.txt` those values end up being identical for each frame, starting at pts=0 / pkt_dts=0 for the first frame, increasing for each frame, and the last two frames even end up having pts=23 / pkt_dts=N/A and pts=24 / pkt_dts=N/A respectively.

This seems wrong to me? These values should not be the same at least for B frames, right? And there certainly are B frames in the written video. Why are these values reset at all somewhere inside the `av_interleaved_write` function? Is there some setting I am missing?

Comment: There is a difference between `pkt_pts` and `pts` and between `pkt_dts` and `dts`. Simple example: **1.** Build synthetic video: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=20 videoOut.mp4` **2.** Execute FFprobe with `-show_frames`: `ffprobe videoOut.mp4 -show_frames > frames.txt` **3.** Execute FFprobe with `-show_packets`: `ffprobe videoOut.mp4 -show_frames > packets.txt`. When using `-show_frames`, it looks like `pkt_pts` = `pkt_dts`. When using `-show_packets`, `pts` != `dts`.  I don't know the difference, but we may Google search: `pkt_pts vs pts`

Comment: @Rotem ok now I am confused even more. You are right, when examining the packets of my output file through `-show_packets` I find those pts and dts values again which I was writing. But this now leaves the question: Which values does a player rely upon when decoding and displaying the "images" of a video? I was thinking those would be rather the frames than the packets? Thing is, the files I create seem to play fine, but I still dont believe the file is writen correctly?

Comment: [AVFrame structure](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/structAVFrame.html) has both `pts` and `pkt_pts`. Try setting `frame->pkt_pts = 0;` and see if there is any affect. I think only `pts` is relevant, but I never checked it out. `pkt_pts` definition: "PTS copied from the AVPacket that was decoded to produce this frame." As I understand it, pkt_pts is relevant only when decoding (and not when encoding).

Comment: `frame->pkt_pts` is "Deprecated: use the pts field instead", changes did not have any effect

Comment: Well I guess when ffmpeg on the command line produces such output, then at least there is nothing wrong on my part, so maybe it just is not an issue

Comment: Since `frame->pkt_pts` is deprecated, I am sure this is not an issue... The only issue I can see is that FFprobe shows `frame->pkt_pts` that is irrelevant, and confusing us. I  conclude that for getting the correct `pts` we can't use `-show_frames` argument, and we should use `-show_packets` instead.

Comment: Have you confirmed the last point @Rotem? This answer for example seems to indicate that frames should be used:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563911/why-is-packet-pts-frame-pkt-pts-in-avframe

Comment: @HebertoMayorquin The answer is from 2015. It may be deprecated sometime between 2015 and 2022. I concluded that `frame->pkt_pts` output of FFprobe are incorrect because the values are wrong. Maybe there is some usage, I am not sure...

Comment: Thanks for the update, truly appreciated it. I have been having troubles myself finding a good source of truth for this one. Have you tried using "best_effort_timestamp" from the probe?